# Problems with comparisons in ANTLR4 grammar

Tags: java, expression, antlr, antlr4, logical-operators

I've build a small parser for writing filters in my application and most of it works fine. But now I noticed something weird. I have comparisons like '==', '!=', '>=' etc and they also work fine. But for some reason antlr (or my grammar) also accepts combinations of them, like '===', '<=!', '!==' etc. And another weird thing is that when I visit the tree for an expression like 'number !== value', antlr have removed the last equal sign in the context.

My grammar is like this:

```
grammar Filter;

filter: expr EOF ;

expr: expr 'and' expr
    | expr 'or' expr
    | 'not' expr
    | '(' expr ')'
    | compExpr
    ;
compExpr: ( operand (EQ | NEQ) operand )
        | ( numOperand (GT | GE | LT | LE) numOperand )
        ;
operand: qualifiedName | nodeId | STR | bool | numOperand ;
numOperand: INT | HEX | TIMESTAMP | qualifiedName ;
bool: TRUE | FALSE ;
qualifiedName: NAME ( '.' NAME )* ;
nodeId: SERIAL ;

GT: '>' ;
GE: '>=' ;
LT: '<' ;
LE: '<=' ;
EQ: '==';
NEQ: '!=' ;
TRUE: 'true' ;
FALSE: 'false' ;
NAME: [a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z0-9_$]* ;
INT: '-'? DIGIT+ ;
STR: '"' (~["])* '"' ;
HEX: '0x' [0-9a-fA-F]+ ;
SERIAL: [0-9a-zA-Z]+ ;
TIMESTAMP: DIGIT DIGIT':'DIGIT DIGIT':'DIGIT DIGIT('.'DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT)? ;
DIGIT: [0-9] ;
WS  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I run the following using your grammar:

```
echo "mike === 5" | grun Filter filter -tokens -tree
```

I get the following output:

```
line 1:7 token recognition error at: '= '
[@0,0:3='mike',<NAME>,1:0]
[@1,5:6='==',<'=='>,1:5]
[@2,9:9='5',<INT>,1:9]
[@3,11:10='<EOF>',<EOF>,2:0]
(filter (expr (compExpr (operand (qualifiedName mike)) == (operand (numOperand 5)))) <EOF>)
```

That tree is consistent with what you see when you're visiting the tree expression.

ANTLR will report the token recognition error, discard that input and attempt to continue parsing.

It appears that you're suppressing the error message about the unrecognized token.  (It would come from the Lexer, so if this is your error reporting code, make sure you have a listener attached to the Lexer as well as the parser.)

It's not uncommon to find a rule like `INVALID: '.';` at the end of your Lexer rules to handle "anything that didn't get picked up by previous Lexer rules.  This avoids any token recognition errors (as EVERYTHING will get a token), and then, since the `INVALID` token won't appear in any parser rules, you'll get parser error instead.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'm using a visitor for a basic verification of the syntax and I have turned off error listeners and INSTEAD using BailErrorStrategy() to get the error as an exception. It works fine for other types of issues, but I don't get any exception for this...

Comment: I don't love it, but adding this to my grammar solved it for now. Then my compExpr would not match in case it tokenizes some INVALID tokens...

`INVALID: '!' | '=' ;`

Comment: I've added a bit of information about a way to handle this in a more generalized fashion (not much different, but it means you won't have to keep adding alternatives if you encounter other characters.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Its odd to me, but it works... :)